# Set peek height programmatically in BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, bottom-sheet

I have a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` that I want to be able to show on any screen. I've spent the day trying to programmatically change the peek height of the sheet, but nothing seems to be changing it.

Here is my layout, `bottom_sheet.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="96dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

You will notice I have an empty `NestedScrollView`. This is because I have made my content customizable when I show the bottom sheet on different screens, so I load a custom layout into it through code.

Here is my fragment class:

```
public class BottomSheetFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    private LinearLayout bottomSheet;
    private NestedScrollView contentView;

    public BottomSheetFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NotNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        bottomSheet = view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
        contentView = view.findViewById(R.id.content);
    }

    // Set the layout of the NestedScrollView by passing a layout ID
    public void setLayout(int layoutId) {
        if (contentView != null) {
            contentView.removeAllViews();

            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutId, contentView, false);

            if (view != null) {
                contentView.addView(view);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, where I want to show the bottom sheet, I do:

```
BottomSheetFragment bottomSheetFragment = new BottomSheetFragment();
bottomSheetFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomSheetFragment.getTag());
```

I want the peek height of the sheet to be 64dp from the top of the screen. How and where would I do this programmatically?

I also found that, even if I change the value of `app:behavior_peekHeight="96dp"` in the layout to something like 500dp, it still doesn't change anything when I show the sheet.

Answer (score 11):

There is no view element in your bottom_sheet. Thats why you dont see any change when play around with `peekheight`.

Set some height to  bottom_sheet to view changes.
If you set the height (300) for example, you will clearly see the peek height taking effect.

For example,

```
<LinearLayout
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="96dp"
            app:behavior_hideable="true">

            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

will Result in

[image]

**To  set peekheight programatically**

First you have to put your bottomsheet in coordinate layout like that

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="96dp"
            app:behavior_hideable="true">

            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In your class, you do that.

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        View bottomSheet = view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
        BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        behavior.setPeekHeight(150); 
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without putting it in a Coordinator Layout? I've found that if I use it, it breaks other things.

Comment: Not really. You have to stick to Coordinator Layout. According to Docs, BottomSheetBehavior is an interaction behavior plugin for a child view of CoordinatorLayout

Comment: CoordinatorLayout works for this height without programmatically changing height. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can set state `STATE_EXPANDED` on BottomSheetShow.
here's my working code snippet.

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        BottomSheetDialog dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

        dialog.setOnShowListener((DialogInterface.OnShowListener) dialog1 -> {
            BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog1;
            FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) d.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
            if (bottomSheet != null)
                BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        });

        return dialog;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

To set the peek height programmatically, you can:

1. Override `onCreateDialog` in your `BottomSheetDialogFragment`
2. Cast as `BottomSheetDialog`
3. Call `setPeekHeight(int, boolean)` on the `behavior` (`BottomSheetBehavior`)

```kotlin
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState).apply {
        (this as? BottomSheetDialog)
                ?.behavior
                ?.setPeekHeight(BottomSheetBehavior.PEEK_HEIGHT_AUTO, true)
    }
}
```

The `BottomSheetBehavior.PEEK_HEIGHT_AUTO` sets a 16:9 ratio, and `true` is whether to animate.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the peek height to your bottom sheet by getting its reference by override `OnCreateDialog` method inside your `BottomSheetFragment`

```
public class BottomSheetFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    private LinearLayout bottomSheet;
    private NestedScrollView contentView;

    public BottomSheetFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NotNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        bottomSheet = view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
        contentView = view.findViewById(R.id.content);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Your code to modify the bottom sheet behavior to set peek height which will be used in collapsed state
     * Here I set it to 80 percent of height of my screen
     * You can directly setPeekHeight() to your requirement
     */
    @NonNull @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

        dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                BottomSheetDialog bottom_dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;

                FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) bottom_dialog.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
                assert bottomSheet != null;
                //BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = requireActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
                int maxHeight = (int) (height*0.80);
                BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setPeekHeight(maxHeight);
            }
        });

        return dialog;
    }

    // Set the layout of the NestedScrollView by passing a layout ID
    public void setLayout(int layoutId) {
        if (contentView != null) {
            contentView.removeAllViews();

            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutId, contentView, false);

            if (view != null) {
                contentView.addView(view);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to overrride `onCreateDialog` and cast the `super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)` to `BottomSheetDialog` that content  the methd `behavior.setPeekHeight(Int)`

```kotlin
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    return (super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState) as BottomSheetDialog).apply {
      behavior.setPeekHeight(resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels / 2)
    }
}
```